# UPDATE THE FIRST CELL IN A CSV FILE USING POWER SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: powershell, header

I already have this file Workspacesize.csv. I am adding a TEST value to cell (1,2) and trying to save. It is asking me for a prompt that the file already exists, do you want to overwrite. I donot want this prompt. I have used  $Excelobject.DisplayAlerts= 'False' but still it does not work.

```
$Excelobject=New-object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excelobject.visible = $False
$workbook=$Excelobject.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\OneDrive - Shell\Desktop\Workspacesize.csv")
$worksheet=$workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.Activate()
$worksheet.cells.item(1,2)="TEST"
$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\OneDrive - Shell\Desktop\Workspacesize.csv")
$workbook.close
$Excelobject.DisplayAlerts= 'False'
$Excelobject.Quit()
```

Comment: Have you tried the CSV-related commands that PowerShell already has? I am not sure Excel is needed. `Get-Command -Name '*-csv*'`

Answer (score 2):

You're better off not using excel for csv files, it unnecessarily complicates things.

```
$Path = "C:\Users\Siddhartha.S.Das2\OneDrive - Shell\Desktop\Workspacesize.csv"
$Content = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$Content[0].Col1 = 'TEST' #Put your actual column name rather than Col1
$Content | Export-Csv -Path $Path
```

Comment: This can work well if the file is not -large-. Using the `-Delimiter` parameter is a good idea. If the file does not have a header record with field names, use the `-Header` parameter. Use `help Import-Csv -Full` for all the details.